# Replace string as you type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a web-friendly image name from user input on a form. I want to replace any spaces in the user entered string with a dash as the user types.

My code only replaces the **first** space.

How do I replace **all** spaces with dashes?

```
$('#form_model').keyup(function(event) {
    var newText = event.target.value; 
    newText = newText.replace(" ", "-");

    $('#form_image').val(newText+".png");
});
```

Comment: Go read up on RegExp _flags_ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done by using a regexpression with the `g` flag. `g` stand for global, so it affects the whole string and **NOT** only the first value.

**Here is the working fiddle:**

```js
$('#form_model').keyup(function(event) {
  var newText = event.target.value;
  newText = newText.replace(/\s/g, "-");
  $('#form_image').val(newText+".png");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="form_model" type="text">
<input id="form_image" type="text" readonly>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace the spaces globally for all the occurrences. So, use this,

```
newText = newText.replace(/ /g, "-");
```

**Final Code**

```
$('#form_model').keyup(function(event) {
var newText = event.target.value; 
newText = newText.replace(/ /g, "-");

$('#form_image').val(newText+".png");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JS function *replace()*  only replace the first character that matches. I usually use

```
.split('X').join('Y');
```

So, in your code it would be:

```
newText = newText.split(' ').join('-');
```

In this way, you can 'replace' all maching characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#form_model').keyup(function(event) {
  var newText = event.target.value; 
  newText = newText.replace(" ", "-");

  $('#form_image').val(newText+".png");
  });
});
```

Example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/55qxy624/